# Asking a question as a community wiki

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I would like to ask a question on the main site that would ask for command line arguments for starcraft 2 and what they do.

I assume answerers would only know part of the existing command line arguments, so they would add it to an existing answer, which is why I think a community wiki question is better.

Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: You would need to turn the answer into a community wiki, then it could serve that purpose. I'm not sure about the scope of that question (depending on how many arguments there are it might be too broad), but if it's fine using a community wiki answer would be a good way to do it.

Comment: so, if it's fine, I ask the question, I answer by posting the arguments I know, and turn the answer into community wiki answer?

Comment: Exactly. You should also make sure someone else didn't already post a question like that or if there's already a list out there on the internet. Posting questions that are easily googled for are frowned upon.